# fb share does not take og:image dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I am writing a website where i would have several pages(user submitted). These pages would be accessed like http://www.mywebsite.com/?page=page1, http://www.mywebsite.com/?page=page2 etc.,  I would want to have a fb-like-share button for each of the pages (after the content is loaded) so that when they click that, it posts that particular page(along with its image) in their fb. So far everything seemed going right for me until i hit this problem that breaks my head last two days. Some forums say open-graph and fb-share are buggy but i still hope my requirement is something global and it must work.

While fb-like and fb-share works fine in sharing the particular URL, it does not pick the right image though. I could define the OG meta tag's in the header but these are bound to change as the pages are loaded through Ajax dynamically.

I overwrite these tags og:url and og:image through jQuery( which shows they are updated ) but fb-share does not read them i guess. (OR How do i test that ? )

FB debugger tool does not seem to help much since I use ajax methods, it does not show the updated meta tags but shows what is defined in my header first time, so it obviously is not of much help to me. if i hard-code my values in the header (without relying on jquery to overwrite) both of my pages individually work fine with its right contents, count and URL that confirms there is not an issue with cache or these tags or with the images i use. But when i club them all to overwrite through java-script there seem to be a disconnect, not sure where.

According to me this is a problem with meta tags getting overwritten using the jquery.
Also, I think the fb-share also does not pick the right url's while showing the count next to it.

In short, fb-share does not get overwritten with the new url's (per the page-id i show) as it shows the same count(like/share) for all of my pages and it does not pick the overwritten meta-tag's to display the right pictures. Anything i hardcode it simply works for the page that is hard-coded.

my index.php runs like this (note i have masked the website details and my fb app)..

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive"/>
<meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="noarchive"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="4126120410011204"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="fbuser1"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="fbuser2"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="MYWEBSITE | A website on cloud being tested..."/>
…

</head>

<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

           …

           var selProfID = $("#profileID").val();

           if (selfProfID ) { 
             showOneProf(selfProfID);
            }

           function showOneProf(uid) {
             ...
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action.php,
            data: {'pageid' : uid},

            success: function(results)
            {
..          
 $.each(eval(results), function(i,item){


        …
        $('head').append('<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/?page='+item.pageid+'" />');
        $('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/'+item.image+'" />');
        var linkurl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/?page=page1";

           document.getElementById('fblike2').setAttribute('href', linkurl);
           document.getElementById("fbcomments1").setAttribute('href', linkurl);
           FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fbc'));
           $("#contents").append(results);
         });
        ..
        });

</script>   

<?php
..

$profid = $_GET['page'];
echo "<input type='hidden' id='profileID' value='$profid'><BR>";

..
<div id='contents'>
<div id="fbc"></div>
<script>
function loadfbComments(){
var elemDiv = document.getElementById("fbc");

    var likes = '<div id="fblike2" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-send="true" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>';
    var markup = '';
        markup += '<div id="fbcomments1" class="fb-comments" data-colorscheme="light" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com" data-order-by="reverse" data-num-posts="10" data-width="682" style="margin-top:2em;"></div>';
        elemDiv.innerHTML = "<BR>" + likes + "<BR>" + markup;
        FB.XFBML.parse(elemDiv);
}
loadfbComments();

                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=09090909090909"></script>
..  
</div>
?>
```

Please help if you think i am making any silly mistakes here. Thanks a lot.

PK

Comment: Facebook will not execute any ajax code on your site, it takes a snapshot of the source when the page is loaded and uses that instead.

Comment: thanks, so how do we dynamically change the meta tags for this kind of requirement so that every page has its own associated fb-share that pulls the right url and image ?

Comment: I'd imagine you'd have to generate the og tags with your PHP, It's probably not the solution you're looking for but Facebook don't seem to offer another alternative :(

Answer (score 3):

As Jamie mentioned in the comment on your post, Facebook just makes a request to your site and takes the header information it finds. Javascript is executed by your browser, not by the simple request Facebook is making. It will only retrieve the static meta tags, not the rendered tags. When you want to make your share image dynamic you should do that on the server-side.

You can set something like:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?= $shareImage ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested this method and it worked too but i am not quite happy in passing these values as query string to my url as it looks ugly. Can that be hidden from the user while we achieve the same through this method or If i did not understand your suggestion clearly , Can you rephrase a bit ? thanks for the help :)

Comment: It shouldn't be in the URL. What I meant was that your php script should decide internally which link and share image should be used. So instead of using $('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/someimage.jpg" />') can just have set $shareImage = "http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/someimage.jpg" and set that as the static meta value as shown in the post above.

Comment: How is your page currently deciding which URL to place in the javascript code?

Comment: I added that piece in my code now. please look once again. In short, I pass "page=<page-id>" as query string in the url , that gets picked up by "GET" and jquery does an ajax call , pulls the data to show it in a div. but this page=<page-id> would not show up in the url as i can do SEO to make it look like http://www.mywebsite.com/page/<page-id> Now please tell me where does your logic fit in so that i can quickly try that. thanks for your help. page contents and the image associated to that page are stored in database that PHP section of code won't know yet.

Comment: In your code it still looks like the meta tags are just static strings. If the link is based on the page parameter in the URL then you can just set <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/?page=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['page']) ?>" />. I don't know whoere the "uploads/someimage.jpg" part is coming from. Are you looking that up in a database somewhere?

Comment: sorry added that portion as well. i wrote the code by hand just to explain what i was doing but not exactly the same script i am using in my system. hope u understand my requirement based on what u see from the example given above. basically the image name comes from the database that pulls the record matching the page-id passed from query string. hope the flow is clear now. At the time when the php sends the query string to the java script, it wont know what would be the image value as it has not fetched it from the db yet which is done by the java script portion.

Comment: Any comments after my last reply ? I am awaiting your help.. thanks.

Comment: guys i cracked it already but did not update it here. What i did ? I just redirected all requests from facebook 1.1 agent (using .htaccess) to a separate php script that sets all these meta tags in the header and nothing else. Basically it mimics the requests coming from facebook would get the response of a page that will only have these meta tags of open-graph. rest of the requests in the .htaccess would go normally. this works beautifully. thanks for the help all through to help me understand how that works.